# Detect filled checkboxes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using [boxdetect 1.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/boxdetect/) to detect the coordinates of the checkboxes.

I am directly using  `get_checkboxes` method with the minor configurations changes

It is detecting this type of checkboxes
[image]

But not able to detect in these cases [image]

Any preprocessing suggestions to make the second type of checkbox detect? or any other type of method which can detect these kinds of checkboxes

Code snippet

```
#pip install boxdetect
from boxdetect.pipelines import get_checkboxes
from boxdetect import config

def default_checkbox_config():
    cfg = config.PipelinesConfig()

    # important to adjust these values to match the size of boxes on your image
    cfg.width_range = (5,35)
    cfg.height_range = (5,35)

    # the more scaling factors the more accurate the results but also it takes more time to processing
    # too small scaling factor may cause false positives
    # too big scaling factor will take a lot of processing time
    cfg.scaling_factors = [10]

    # w/h ratio range for boxes/rectangles filtering
    cfg.wh_ratio_range = (0.5, 1.7)

    # group_size_range starting from 2 will skip all the groups
    # with a single box detected inside (like checkboxes)
    cfg.group_size_range = (2, 100)

    # num of iterations when running dilation tranformation (to engance the image)
    cfg.dilation_iterations = 0
    return cfg

def divide_checkbox(checkboxes,crop_image_file,pdf_file_name):
    img = cv2.imread(crop_image_file)
    checkbox_counter = 0  
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        checkbox_counter+=1
        cropped = img[checkbox[0][1]:checkbox[0][1]+checkbox[0][3],checkbox[0][0]:checkbox[0][2]+checkbox[0][0]]
        # mpimg.imsave("checkbox_image/out{}{}.png".format(pdf_file_name,checkbox_counter), cropped)
        plt.imshow(cropped)
        plt.show()

def get_all_checkboxes(crop_image_file,pdf_file_name):
    cfg = default_checkbox_config()
    checkboxes = get_checkboxes(
        crop_image_file, cfg=cfg, px_threshold=0.1, plot=False, verbose=True)
    divide_checkbox(checkboxes,crop_image_file,pdf_file_name)
try:
    pdf_file_name = "something"
    crop_image_file= "shady_tick3.png" #just give your image path
    get_all_checkboxes(crop_image_file,pdf_file_name)
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you include the original, unprocessed image.